# AngularJS: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- productService

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a *Service* to pull data from database using Web API controller method. But whenever I inject the service and call the service method in controller, it shows the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- productService
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20productService

Tried a lot but cannot understand where the wrong actually lies!

**Here is My AngularJS Module Code:**

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
```

**Here is my RouteConfig**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/products/details/:id",
        {
            templateUrl: "Temaplates/details.html",
            controller: "productDetailsController"
        })
 })
```

**Here is My Service:**

```
app.factory('productService',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        return {
            getDataById: function() {
                alert("Hello I am invoked");
                $http({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "http://localhost:43618/api/Products",
                        params: { id: $routeParams.id }
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        $scope.product = response.data;
                    })
            }
        };
    });
```

**Here is my AngularJS Controller**

```
app.controller("productDetailsController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, productService) {
     $scope.message = "Product Details";
     $scope.product = productService.getDataById();

    })
```

**Where is the wrong actually!! Any Help Please!!**

Comment: $routeProvider.when("/products/details/:id",
not like $routeProvider..when("/products/details/:id",

Comment: Haha!! This was not the problem actually!! This is just typing mistake :)

Comment: "/products/details/"+id

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several things which I wanted to note down

1. You can't inject `$scope` inside service
2. You should return `$http.get` promise from service method to get data inside controller.
3. Inside controller use `.then` to retrieve data from service function.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('productService',
  function($http, $routeParams) {
    return {
      getDataById: function() {
            //return proimise from here
        return $http.get("http://localhost:43618/api/Products", {
            params: { id: $routeParams.id }
        });
      }
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("productDetailsController", function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, productService) {
    $scope.message = "Product Details";
    productService.getDataById().then(function(response){
      $scope.product = response.data;
    }, function(error){
      console.log("Error occured ", error);
    });
});
```

Comment: @TanvirArjel Thanks, Glad to know that :)

Comment: @Pankaj_Parkar, It's showing product is not defined! error!!

Comment: @TanvirArjel there was a extra bracket, just check the updated

Comment: It finally works!! Thanks for your effort..would you tell me  please where the extra bracket actually was!!

Comment: You can check the difference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40691588/revisions)

Answer (score 5):

You can't inject $scope into a service  as specific scopes are only available in directives and components. You can only use $rootScope

This actually makes sense because a service is a singleton. When injected into multiple controllers, which $scope should angular use then? $rootScope on the other hand is also a singleton so that works.

Comment: Thanks!! Would be great if you rewrite/changes my code according to output and submit as answer!

Comment: I would, but am on my phone. Figured I'd give you an answer so you could get going.